# Как подключить функцию php

Tags: php, html

Здрасьте.

Есть самая верхняя строчка на странице, так сказать, самый верхный header. В ней на сайтах часто располагается контактная информация (телефоны, адреса, прочее), так вот, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы элементы `<a><img></a>` были видны лишь спустя сотку-две пикселей прокрутки. Я призадумалась, поискала и нашла такой код:

```
<?php function scroll_block(){
var stop = (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop);
var el=document.getElementById('menublock');
if(stop>150){
if(el.style.display!='block'){ 
el.style.display='block'; 
}
}
else 
el.style.none='none';

return false;
}

if (window.addEventListener){
window.addEventListener("scroll", scroll_block, false);
window.addEventListener("load", scroll_block, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent){
window.attachEvent("onscroll", scroll_block);
window.attachEvent("onload", scroll_block);
}

<div id='menublock' style="display:none">а тут меню</div>
?>
```

Затем я подумала, и теперь сделала сам элемент:

```
<div id="hideousvar">
<a href="http://dev.zoldol.ru/vremya-raboty-sklonov">
<img class="varhid" style="padding: 0px 5px 12px 5px;height: 25px;" title="Время работы склонов" alt="" src="http://dev.zoldol.ru/wp-content/themes/subway-child/images/clock.png"></a>

<a href="http://dev.zoldol.ru/webcamera">
<img class="varhid" style="padding: 0px 5px 10px 5px;height: 28px;" title="WEB-камера" alt="" src="http://dev.zoldol.ru/wp-content/themes/subway-child/images/camera.png"></a>

<a href="http://dev.zoldol.ru/3d-tour">
<img class="varhid" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;height: 35px;" title="3D-тур" alt="" src="http://dev.zoldol.ru/wp-content/themes/subway-child/images/tour.png"></a>

<a href="http://dev.zoldol.ru/scheme">
<img  class="varhid" style="padding: 0px 5px 13px 5px;
height: 24px;" title="Интерактивная карта склона" alt="" src="http://dev.zoldol.ru/wp-content/themes/subway-child/images/map.png"></a>
</div>
```

Функция:

```
<?php
    function scroll_block(){
        var stop = (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop);
        var el=document.getElementById('hideousvar');
            if(stop>150){
            if(el.style.display!='block'){ 
                    el.style.display='block'; 
                        }
                        }
        else 
            el.style.none='none';

            return false;
            }

        if (window.addEventListener){
            window.addEventListener("scroll", scroll_block, false);
            window.addEventListener("load", scroll_block, false);
                }
        else if (window.attachEvent){
            window.attachEvent("onscroll", scroll_block);
            window.attachEvent("onload", scroll_block);
            }

    <div id='hideousvar' style="display:none">а тут меню</div>
?>
```

Но что-то не сработало. Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Буду безмерно благодарна за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ИЗВИНИТЕ, ЧТО ЭТО ТАКОЕ?

Вы определитесь, код на каком языке вы пишете, на PHP, или же JS.

А не сработало то, что у вас из за незнакомых функций, и непонятного синтаксиса PHP просто напросто накушался фатал-эрроров, и ушёл плакать.

Всё, что у Вас обёрнуто в <?php  ?> - обверните вместо этого в <script></script>, и я не удивлюсь, если всё заработает.

Либо сделайте так:

```
<?php
echo '
<script>
function scroll_block(){
var stop = (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop);
var el=document.getElementById(\'menublock\');
if(stop>150){
if(el.style.display!=\'block\'){ 
el.style.display=\'block\'; 
}
}
else 
el.style.none=\'none\';

    return false;
    }

    if (window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scroll_block, false);
    window.addEventListener("load", scroll_block, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent){
    window.attachEvent("onscroll", scroll_block);
    window.attachEvent("onload", scroll_block);
    }
    </script>
    <div id='menublock' style="display:none">а тут меню</div>
    ';

    ?>
```

По сабжу.

Функция в РНР лепится так:

```
<?php
function some_function(){
// Тело функции
}
?>
```

Вызывается так:

```
<?php
some_function();
?>
```

Пример:

```
<?php
function say_me($replic){
echo $replic;
}

$replic = 'Привет';
say_me($replic);

?>
```

Пример, кончено, очень топорный, но я хотел заложить туда самое главное - очевидность.

А так посоветую вам почитать чуть-чуть литературы, дабы разобраться, где проходит грань между языками программирования.

Comment: Да поняла я уже, что от дурака не далеко ушла. Посмеялась.

Спасибо, в общем, и на том.

Comment: @Anna Frank, я не знаю, что вы именно увидели в моём ответе, однако я вам дал именно тот ответ, который Вас интересовал - что нужно сделать. 

А если вы хотели получить результат по типу "Вот я сюда залью, и за меня всё сделают", то Ваше желание принципиально не исполнимо. 

И всё же, последуйте совету.

Answer (score 1):

Если не написать `echo "here is javascript code"`, php будет думать, что это php код, хотя на самом деле javascript. Использовать javascript  в php можно, но для этого нужно передавать javascript в качестве строки, например, так:  `<?php echo "<script>document.write('hello, world');</script>"; ?>` Вместо echo можно использовать любую php-функцию, выводящую текст (print, sprintf). На данный момент так редко делают, потому что достаточно сложно читать javascript  и php вместе взятые, поэтому их разделяют по отдельным файлам и папкам. Так делают в любой CMS.

Comment: @Vladislav  Romarov ну, тут случай маленько другой. 
Я думаю, из поста сразу понятно было, что человек достаточно далёк от программирования вообще, и ему не принципиальна структура проекта, что и как делают, и НЕ делают. 

Просто девочка пыталась сделать, как могла. ) Конечно, это не возбраняется - любопытство наказывать нельзя, просто нужно направить в нужное русло.

Comment: Мне кажется, что она просто на тебя обиделась xD. Понятно, конечно, но мимо  пройти не могу(иногда возникает что-то вроде *о! Надо зайти на stackoverflow*.)

Comment: @Vladislav  Romarov я конечно по форумам какую только фигню не видел, но что б вот так взяли и ОБИДЕЛИСЬ...

Comment: что за бред вы несете?